# How to create java.lang.reflect.Type

Tags: java

I have the following implementation:

```
   public boolean canWrite(Type type, Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        if (!type.getTypeName().contains("TypeX")) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I would like to test this method, therefore I need to pass in a Type parameter.

In my test, how do I construct the Type parameter for a List of type X?

Spring somehow can populate the type such that it contains a Type name of `List<x.y.y.TypeX>`. I want to do the same thing in my tests.

Comment: What do you mean by construct a type parameter?

Comment: @RomanC: since the method shown has a parameter of type `Type` and the title of the question refers to `java.lang.reflect.Type`, I assume that the OP is asking for a way to construct an object of type `Type` to pass as a parameter, as opposed to constructing a "type parameter" in the sense of a parameter to a generic type or method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to create an instance of the type you want in your test, and extract the `Type` object reflectively:

```
public final class MyTest {
    private final List<TypeX> listOfTypeX = null;
    private final Type typeOfListOfTypeX = MyTest.class
        .getDeclaredField("listOfTypeX")
        .getGenericType();
}
```

As an aside, if the `MediaType` mentioned in your question is in fact Guava's `com.google.common.net.MediaType`, then you also have access to Guava's [`com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), which provides a simpler way to do this:

```
Type typeOfListOfTypeX = new TypeToken<List<TypeX>>() {}.getType();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing,
use a testing tool to create a mock of `Type`.

With Mockito and JUnit,
this will look something like this:

```
@Mock
private java.lang.reflect.Type mockType;

@Before
private void beforeTest()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void useTheMockTest()
{
     ... do your test.
}
```

Comment: `Type` objects are required to have specific semantics around their `equals` and `hashCode` implementations. I would avoid mocking them whenever possible, as it will likely make your test code brittle.